# Function| Domain & Range

Tags: functions

Suppose that A={0,1,2,3,4}, B={2,3,4,5}, 
f={(0,3),(1,3),(2,4),(3,2),(4,2)}

Find the domain and range of f. 
f(1)=? f(2)=?

My opinion is; f(1)=3 and f(2)=4

If I am right, what would be f(2) if there was also (2,3) in f?
**Edit**: I read the definition of a function and I understand that (2,3) cannot be in f. Because, if it was, f would not be a function.

And my opinion is; the domain is {0,1,2,3,4} and the range is {2,3,4}

Finally, is codomain and range are the same thing?

Thank you :)

Comment: Check out the following link to help format this and future questions.

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about what $ f (2) $ and $ f (1) $ equal. The range is $ {2,3,4} $. If there was a $(2,3) $ also, $ f $ wouldn't be a function. And yes codomain is the same as range.

Comment: Thank you so much :) Finally, for f={(x,4x+5):x€Z}. Domain and Range is Z, and f(10) is 45, right? :) I just want to be sure..

Comment: @AYARcom It'a not a line no. And the way it is define above, $ f(10) $ doesn't exist because 10 is not apart of the domain you defined above, a.k.a $ A $. If you mean $\mathbb {Z} $, as in integers, the whole integers is not the domain and range. The function is not continuous it has a domain ${0,1,2,3,4 } $ and range ${2,3,4}$. The function is discrete. It only exists for what you defined above.

Comment: Oh, actually this was another question..

Comment: @AYARcom Oh, makes sense why I was confused. Yes $\mathbb {Z} $ is the domain and range of the function you just stated.